# Convert oracle to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

Iam trying to convert from Oracle to PostgreSQL. I am getting function `SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,2881,SDO_POINT_TYPE(longitude, latitude,null),null,null),4326)` lat.
I have to execute it in pgadmin4.i am getting an error like function SDO_POINT_TYPE(public.grometry,public.geometry,unknown,unknown) does not exist
You might need to add explicit type cast

Comment: So what does the Oracle query do? You'll probably need to install PostGIS if you want to do any serious work with GIS data in Postgres

Comment: Probably `st_setsrid(st_makepoint(longitude, latitude), 4326)`